# jQuery event delegation in 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, event-delegation, jquery-on

Is there any way to delegate an event using jQuery that will correspond to all elements on the page that match the selector, other than delegating from `$(document)`?

Since that's probably poorly worded, here's the rub:

There used to be `jQuery.live` that delegated events to all elements that matched the selector.  This was superseded by `jQuery.delegate` which delegated events within a specific context selector to its children, which in turn was superseded by `jQuery.on`, which does effectively the same thing, but with different bits behind the scenes (I'd imagine).

What I want to do, is safely add an event handler to every `div.foo` on my page, regardless of where it might live, or when it might live.  According to the documentation, and empirical research, the following will only bind to `.foo` elements that exist when the script is run.  Since there is code that might place a `.foo` element on the page later, this doesn't exactly work.

```
jQuery('.foo').on('click', handler);
```

Since `live` is deprecated (possibly removed?), I'm trying to not use that, but the only solution I can come up with is

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.foo', handler);
```

But isn't this what `live` did originally, behind the scenes?   More to the point, are there any significant reasons *not* to do this?

We're specifically using version 1.7.2, but generic jQuery answers would help too.

Comment: This is what `live` did originally, but it's also exactly what you're looking for.  Ideally you would use something other than `document`, however if you can't narrow it down then `document` is your only choice.

Comment: @JamesMontagne yea I suspected as much.  I just didn't know if there was a reason to *not* delegate back to the document, other than the potential for `stopPropagation` to get in the way.

Comment: Also performance.  It has to bubble all the way up and every click on the page gets caught and checked to see if it is the right selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events bubble from their source, to whatever they're delegated, so you should use jquery().on at what ever level is the lowest common parent. If that's document, then so be it.

Otherwise, if your `.foo` items are always created within a `.foocontainer` (or something) then you can use that in your selector, even if there is more than one of them - you just end up attaching.

I think the issue with delegating back to document is that it potentially requires the event to bubble a large number of times, incurring extra overhead in the process, so best to delegate the event as close to the source as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that binding to the document (as below) is exactly what `live()` does:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.foo', handler);
```

The reason this is bad is because it is not very performant. Every time you click, anywhere, the `document` checks to see if it was on the delegated element.

The better method is to use an element in place of `document` which is the closest parent to those which are being dynamically appended, but which is available on page load. Even if this is a top-level container, it would still offer a performance benefit over attaching everything to `document`.