# Call a jQuery Function with onClick event of Image Button

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form in which a table of dynamic data is built with PHP.  Within each row is an image that when clicked calls a jQuery function with a click event.

For example, if the image has an id of eventnfo_0, i have a function like this:

```
$("#eventnfo_0").click(function()
```

It all works fine as long as I have a defined click event for each row.  The problem is, I need to make it dynamic because the number of rows can vary so it's not feasible to build a separate function as depicted above for each row.

My thought is there must be a way to call a jQuery function from an onclick event and pass a row number, but thus far, no dice.

I'm sure it's not an uncommon task, but I've not had any luck with my searches.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways tyo do this... call a same class in each img and use it as a selector...

```
$('.yourClassName').click(function(){alert($(this).attr('id'));});
```

**OR**

```
 $("[id^='eventnfo_']").click(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
 });
```

since it is dynamically added this might help..

```
$(document).on('click',"[id^='eventnfo_']".click(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
 });
```

**updated**

you can use a `data` attributes for a rownumber and get it from jquery..

say this is your html.

```
 <img id="eventnfo_0" data-rownumber="1"/>
```

and jquery

```
$("[id^='eventnfo_']").click(function(){
     alert($(this).data('rownumber')); //this will alert 1
 });
```

Comment: Your second suggestion is working, but I need to pass a row number to the function so that I can get the appropriate event id from a hidden field.  Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[id^='eventnfo_']").click(function(){
   alert(this.attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for dynamic rows you can not use `.click`, You should go with `.on` method which is the preferred way.

JS code

```
$("#table_id").on("click","tr [id^='eventnfo_']", function(){
 //your code goes here.
});
```

Above is called jQuery event delegation. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322342/jquery-event-delegation-in-1-7-2)